# cardio program to be performed in the gym

Tags: cardio

I have had a knee injury from boxing and I need to stay away from road running.

Does anyone know of any good online cardio fitness programmes.

I've been searching online and I cannot find anything that fits my needs.

Comment: Did your physio/doc/whomever give you any insight into what activities to avoid and which ones are okay?

Comment: running is the main one, the impact on the concrete was what caused it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for specific program recommendations, you could always try Athlean-X. It isn’t about cardio exclusively, but it’s oriented around training like an athlete. Which means that conditioning is important, and you don’t have to worry about getting that from running specifically (which seems to be along the lines of what you’re looking for).

Here is a recent video of his to give you an idea of what his approach is like...
https://youtu.be/IitCDC9vrMA

... and here is the full workout that those two did.
https://youtu.be/7hMPWBvq8OY

Comment: +1 for Athlean-X. Jeff Cavaliere is just a wealth of knowledge.